# Changing the icon in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

I have a class that extends `JOptionPane`. In it there's a method that calls `showConfirmDialog (new JFrame(), (JScrollPane) jp, "Friends List", 2, 0, icon);`

Is there a way to change the icon without having to call `showConfirmDialog` a second time? That is, based on my input in the `JOptionPane`, can I change the icon without making a new confirm dialog?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question?  Do you want to change the icon while the dialog is on the screen?  Also, you don't `new JFrame()` as the first parameter, you can pass `null`, but it's better practice to pass a component that this visible on the screen, if you have one

Comment: Yes, I want to change the icon while the dialog is on the screen.

Comment: By it's nature, the `JOptionPane` dialogs are blocking, the only way to even attempt to change it would be to have background thread "might" be able to interact with the instance of the `JOptionPane`...You get the can of worms, I'll get the can opener

Comment: so look for another solution, got it thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right, but you may be able to leverage the approach shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup), you can add a `JOptionPane` to a `Dialog` and listen for the desired `PropertyChangeEvent`. The example below switches between two `UIManager` icons in response to clicking the buttons.

[image]

```
JDialog d = new JDialog();
d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
final Icon PENDING = UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage");
final Icon MISSING = UIManager.getIcon("html.missingImage");
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Click a Button",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getPropertyName().equals(JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY)) {
            Integer value = (Integer) e.getNewValue();
            if (value.intValue() == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                optionPane.setIcon(PENDING);
            } else {
                optionPane.setIcon(MISSING);
            }
        }
    }
});
d.setContentPane(optionPane);
d.pack();
d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
d.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Didn't quite figure out the `PropertyChangeListener` support :P +1