# JOptionPane - show dialog of my own JDialog sub class

Tags: java, swing, oop, dialog

Say I have a `class MyDialogClass extends JDialog`, which I use everywhere in my application, in order to acheive some specific behaviour of my dialogs. Now, I also want to enjoy the benefits of `JOptionPane` utilities, and call `showXxxDialog` to view messages / errors etc., but I still want the underlying dialogs to behave as a `MyDialogClass` instances.

Is it possible to achive (prefferably without deeply replicating the source of `JOptionPane`)?

**EDIT:**

The specific behaviour I am trying to acheive is setting the dialog `alwaysOnTop` to `true`. I will try @Andrew's solution for this issue. BUT, this is only the current problem I'm facing, and not the only extended behaviour in `MyDialogClass`. So there might be such "workaround" for every single problem, but I was intentionaly looking for a conceptual solution, which is the reason for putting my question as I originally did.

[[For instance - `MyDialogClass` also registeres a `WindowListener` to it's instances in the constructor]]

Comment: *"..some specific behaviour of my dialogs."*  ..It never occurred to you that it might be handy to mention the specific behavior required?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Answer (score 2):

You can display a `JDialog` in a `JOptionPane`, as shown in [*How to Make Dialogs: Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup).

> In this case, you must implement your own property change listener so that when the user clicks a button, the dialog does not automatically close.

Related examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16827772/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want .. Do you want to use a dialog from JOptionPane but using your own JPanel? Did you try:

```
Object[] options = { "Yes", "No", "Cancel" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JFrame, YOURPANEL, "Information",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);
```

Comment: I want more then my own panel, I want my own dialog class. Something like: `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JFrame, MyDialogClass.class, "Information",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);`
What I'm realy trying to do, in this case, is call the dialog's `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`.

Comment: *"is call the dialog's `setAlwaysOnTop(true).`"*  The solution is to provide a parent component that is always on top.